# command to identify distinct field value

Tags: unix

Could anyone help me on a command to identify distinct values from a particular column ?

For eg my input is like

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
a   11  abc
a   22  abc
b   33  edf
c   44  ghi
```

I require a output like

```
Column1
a
b
c
```

my input file has header. So i need a command in which we pass Column1 as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command, with an input file:

```
$ head -1 input.file | awk '{ print $1}'; awk '{ if (NR > 1) print $1 }' input.file | uniq
Column1
a
b
c
```

Or just:

```
$ awk '{print $1 }' input.file | uniq
Column1
a
b
c
```

Comment: thank you! Need one more clarification .. Here we know column1 is first field incase if we are not aware in which position is column1 available then what will be the command?

Answer (score 0):

File `distinct.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$_ = <STDIN>;
@F = split;
map $col{$F[$_]}=$_, (0..$#F);          # map column names to numbers
while (<STDIN>)
{
    @F = split;
    $val{$F[$col{$ARGV[0]}]} = undef    # implement the set of values
}
$, = "\n";
print $ARGV[0], "";                     # output the column parameter
print sort(keys %val), ""               # output sorted set of values
```

Example command: `distinct.pl Column2 <input`

Note: Non-existent column names yield the values from the first column.